# Code pipeline to build a branch on pull request

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild

I am trying to make a code pipeline which will build my branch when I make a pull request to the master branch in AWS. I have many developers working in my organisation and all the developers work on their own branch. I am not very familiar with ccreating lambda function. Hoping for a solution

Comment: where is your git-repo? CodeCommit or Github?

Comment: The git-repo is in Code commit

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically change branches on AWS CodePipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829167/dynamically-change-branches-on-aws-codepipeline)

Comment: But is it possible to dynamically change the branch?

Answer (score 2):

You can dynamically create pipelines everytime a new pull-request has been created. Look for the CodeCommit Triggers (in the old CodePipeline UI), you need lambda for this.

Basically it works like this: Copy existing pipeline and update the the source branch.

It is not the best, but afaik the only way to do what you want.

I was there and would not recommend it for the following reasons:

- I hit this limit of 20 in my region: "Maximum number of pipelines with change detection set to periodically checking for source changes" - but, you definitely want this feature ( https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/limits.html )
- The branch-deleted trigger does not work correctly, so you can not delete the created pipeline, when the branch has been merged into master.

I would recommend you to use Github.com if you need a workflow as you described.  Sorry for this.

Comment: As stated in your URL, simply use recommended change detection methods instead of periodic checks in your pipelines to avoid this limit. I assume they mean GitHub webhooks.

Answer (score 2):

I have recently implemented an approach that uses CodeBuild GitHub webhook support to run initial unit tests and build, and then publish the source repository and built artefacts as a zipped archive to S3.

You can then use the S3 archive as a source in CodePipeline, where you can then transition your PR artefacts and code through Integration testing, Staging deployments etc...

This is quite a powerful pattern, although one trap here is that if you have a lot of pull requests being created at a single time, you can get CodePipeline executions being superseded given only one execution can proceed through a given stage at a time (this is actually a really important property, especially if your integration tests run against shared resources and you don't want multiple instances of your application running data setup/teardown tasks at the same time).  To overcome this, I publish an S3 notification to an SQS FIFO queue when CodeBuild publishes the S3 artifact, and then poll the queue, copying each artifact to a different S3 location that triggers CodePipeline, but only if there are are currently no executions waiting to execute after the first CodePipeline source stage.

Answer (score 0):

We can very well have dynamic branching support with the following approach.

One of the limitations in AWS code-pipeline is that we have to specify branch names while creating the pipeline. We can however overcome this issue using the architecture shown below.

[flow diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zmc5b.png)

Create a Lambda function which takes the GitHub web-hook data as input, using boto3 integrate it with AWS pipeline(pull the pipeline and update), have an API gateway to make the call to the Lambda function as a rest call and at last create a web-hook to the GitHub repository.

External links:

- https://aws.amazon.com/quickstart/architecture/git-to-s3-using-webhooks/
- https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/codepipeline.html

Related thread: [Dynamically change branches on AWS CodePipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48829167/dynamically-change-branches-on-aws-codepipeline/)