# AWS CodeBuild - When updating Environment on a Build Project, getting a super unhelpful error message

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-codebuild

while rolling out a build server, i realized that my existing build server was unable to talk to resources within my VPC environment as it was building, and sure enough after checking the CodeBuild project environment there was no VPC / Security Group / Subnet configured

Under AWS CodeBuild > Developer Tools > CodeBuild > Build projects > `<my project>` > Edit Environment

After attempting to add it to my VPC, and to add it to the security group and subnet where I manage HTTP servers, i get this really unhelpful error when trying to save

[image]

`The policy is attached to 2 entities but it must be attached to a single role`

where do i even start to fix whatever this error message is talking about?

the role has only one policy

###### attached policy:

```json
{
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action": [
                "iam:PassRole"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEqualsIfExists": {
                    "iam:PassedToService": [
                        "cloudformation.amazonaws.com",
                        "elasticbeanstalk.amazonaws.com",
                        "ec2.amazonaws.com",
                        "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codecommit:CancelUploadArchive",
                "codecommit:GetBranch",
                "codecommit:GetCommit",
                "codecommit:GetRepository",
                "codecommit:GetUploadArchiveStatus",
                "codecommit:UploadArchive"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codedeploy:CreateDeployment",
                "codedeploy:GetApplication",
                "codedeploy:GetApplicationRevision",
                "codedeploy:GetDeployment",
                "codedeploy:GetDeploymentConfig",
                "codedeploy:RegisterApplicationRevision"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codestar-connections:UseConnection"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "elasticbeanstalk:*",
                "ec2:*",
                "elasticloadbalancing:*",
                "autoscaling:*",
                "cloudwatch:*",
                "s3:*",
                "sns:*",
                "cloudformation:*",
                "rds:*",
                "sqs:*",
                "ecs:*"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "lambda:InvokeFunction",
                "lambda:ListFunctions"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "opsworks:CreateDeployment",
                "opsworks:DescribeApps",
                "opsworks:DescribeCommands",
                "opsworks:DescribeDeployments",
                "opsworks:DescribeInstances",
                "opsworks:DescribeStacks",
                "opsworks:UpdateApp",
                "opsworks:UpdateStack"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:CreateStack",
                "cloudformation:DeleteStack",
                "cloudformation:DescribeStacks",
                "cloudformation:UpdateStack",
                "cloudformation:CreateChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DeleteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:DescribeChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:ExecuteChangeSet",
                "cloudformation:SetStackPolicy",
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Action": [
                "codebuild:BatchGetBuilds",
                "codebuild:StartBuild",
                "codebuild:BatchGetBuildBatches",
                "codebuild:StartBuildBatch"
            ],
            "Resource": "*",
            "Effect": "Allow"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "devicefarm:ListProjects",
                "devicefarm:ListDevicePools",
                "devicefarm:GetRun",
                "devicefarm:GetUpload",
                "devicefarm:CreateUpload",
                "devicefarm:ScheduleRun"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "servicecatalog:ListProvisioningArtifacts",
                "servicecatalog:CreateProvisioningArtifact",
                "servicecatalog:DescribeProvisioningArtifact",
                "servicecatalog:DeleteProvisioningArtifact",
                "servicecatalog:UpdateProduct"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudformation:ValidateTemplate"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ecr:DescribeImages"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "states:DescribeExecution",
                "states:DescribeStateMachine",
                "states:StartExecution"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "appconfig:StartDeployment",
                "appconfig:StopDeployment",
                "appconfig:GetDeployment"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ],
    "Version": "2012-10-17"
}
```

Comment: Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64700445/unable-to-create-pipeline-because-of-service-role

Comment: @Caldazar unfortunately didnt provide any leads. but i will include the attached policy to the role in my OP.