# Module level directives cause errors when bundled, 'use client' was ignored causing JavaScript heap out of memory

Tags: reactjs, vite, aws-pipeline

I had this error in my pipeline aws:
Module level directives cause errors when bundled, 'use client' was ignored causing JavaScript heap out of memory

I want a solution for this problem considering that i am using vite.js on my react.js app.

Answer (score 6):

to resolve this question i used 2 steps:
1 - add this code into vite.config.js:

```
    export default defineConfig({
  build: {
    chunkSizeWarningLimit: 100,
    rollupOptions: {
    onwarn(warning, warn) {
      if (warning.code === 'MODULE_LEVEL_DIRECTIVE') {
        return
      }
      warn(warning)
    }}
  },
  plugins: [react()],
  
});
```

2 - I used this config in my aws pipeline:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/66889948/13507783